# WSL2 - VSCode's shell command `code` no longer working in Linux terminal

Tags: command-line, 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am very new to Linux and WSL overall. I was able to use `code .` to open my current directory in VSCode, but after deleting something that I do not remember it just doesn't work anymore. I put in the command and it just hangs there.

I have deleted my Ubuntu-20.04 instance and recreated it, but still it will not work. Also checked my $PATH and it seems to be there.

Also, the `add shell command` in VSCode does not come up, so I can't uninstall and reinstall the shell shortcut.

Anyone have any idea?

```
drewbie@drewbie:/$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/Go/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/heroku/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Andrew/go/bin:/snap/bin
```

[image: After inputing code . it just sits there]

whereis and which

```
drewbie@drewbie:~$ whereis code
code: /mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code /mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code.cmd
drewbie@drewbie:~$ which code
/mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
```

After doing what @NotTheDr01ds said in the thread below

```
drewbie@drewbie:~$ vi "$(which code)"
drewbie@drewbie:~$ code .
+ [  = true ]
+ COMMIT=899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3
+ APP_NAME=code
+ QUALITY=stable
+ NAME=Code
+ DATAFOLDER=.vscode
+ realpath /mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
+ dirname /mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin
+ VSCODE_PATH=/mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code
+ ELECTRON=/mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe
+ IN_WSL=false
+ [ -n Ubuntu-20.04 ]
+ IN_WSL=true
+ [ true = true ]
+ export WSLENV=ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE/w:WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID
+ wslpath -m /mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js
+ CLI=C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js
+ WSL_EXT_ID=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
+ ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE=1 /mnt/c/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe C:/Users/Andrew/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/out/cli.js --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node --locate-extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl
```

Comment: Can you uninstall and reinstall the *Remote - WSL* extension in VSCode?  At worst, how about uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode itself?  I don't usually resort to "reinstall" as the first go-to- answer, but given (a) you aren't sure what you deleted, and (b) reinstalling is pretty quick and painless, I think it's worth a shot first.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I uninstalled and re-installed `Remote - WSL` extension, but still it did not fix it. I am a bit hesitant in uninstalling VSCode. As a last hail mary, maybe. But not yet.

Comment: Fair enough.  `code` is actually a shell script, so you can try debugging it to potentially see where it's hanging.  `vi $(which code)` and add `set -x` as the first line after the shebang.  Then try running and add the output to the question.  I can compare it to mine, at least.

Comment: I tried to do what you did, with no avail. :( I was able to figure out which code it is using and where it is. Not sure if there's some symlink I need to do? I see that thrown around sometimes.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's probably due to the spaces in the path.  That's my bad - I should know to quote things like that.  Try it with quotes - `vi "$(which code)"`?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I got it to work! Posting it in my question above. Thank you so much for your help so far!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this issue was caused to me by an update of VSCode, which happened automatically.

To solve it:

1. open VSCode in Windows
2. open the Remote Explorer

   [image: Remote Explorer]
3. click on a folder in a WSL target of interest: you'll see that this causes some re-installation
4. now you can go back to using the `$ code .` command from a folder in WSL2, just like you used to

Comment: Dang. I'd check this, but I decided just to dual boot Linux instead on a separate drive. If anyone can validate this I'll make it the answer!

Comment: @Ando despite being a member for over 7 years, you still haven't taken the [tour]; please do.

Comment: This didn't work for me but it was helpful in getting me to realise that the problem had started after I added a remote ssh connection.

Answer (score 7):

Since the accepted answer relies on side effects and did not work for me, and the second one is totally unacceptable (complete resinstall of WSL) I searched a bit more and found **a safer and effective way**:

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64108941/visual-studio-code-not-running-working-on-wsl-2) older question in StackOverflow, answered by [rrmesquita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64108942/2628864):

> Within the WSL terminal, type `rm -r ~/.vscode-server` to delete the
> VS Code WSL server.
>
> Exit the terminal and from your PowerShell/Cmd, run `wsl --shutdown` .
> Then you can log in back to your WSL and run `code .`  and it should
> work normally.

Answering because Google led me here and maybe this will make life easier for someone else =)

Comment: this fixed my VS Code Internal Terminal not opening up in CWD

Comment: +1 for me, this worked a treat. Incidentally `code . --verbose` was also helpful as it showed me that vs code was just hanging, initially I had assumed it was silently exiting every time I tried to invoke it.

Comment: **Note**: adding "/mnt" to $PATH will cause high input latency on WSL2 terminal.

Comment: Before i try this, can anyone confirm if you lose all the settings for that folder/workspace?

Comment: @TrojanName you could always just do `mv` instead of `rm` if you're afraid it will mess your stuff. Backup =)

Comment: I ask because in my case it wouldn't be worth losing all the settings. Anyway I can confirm that it doesn't lose the settings, but sadly neither does it fix the problem in my case. code still hangs on the command. Ctrl-c brings back the cursor so it's not the end of the world, but it would be nice to solve it

Comment: Removing the ~/.vscode-server dir removes plugins installed in the remote host. In my case just `wsl --shutdown` from the Windows PowerShell, then logging back in to WSL and running `code .` fixed it

Answer (score 5):

I just added this to my .bashrc:

```
alias code='/mnt/c/Users/[YOUR USER DIR NAME]/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code'
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up getting it to work in the end. I believe it was the following that fixed it.

1. Go to your Terminal and delete your `settings.json` file.  You make wish to save a backup first.
   [image: The said file opened from the terminal]
2. You are going to `ctrl-a`, delete it all, then SAVE THE FILE.
3. Very important step. When you go back to your Terminal, click SAVE in the bottom right corner.
   [image: Save button click it!]
4. Now, this is not fun, but we are going to unregister **Ubuntu-20.04** from the powershell.

   **Note**:  This is a **destructive** operation, and all data inside the WSL instance's filesystem will be lost.  Again, before this step, you may wish to take a backup first with `wsl --export Ubuntu-20.04 <backup-filename.tar>` to be safe.  When you are ready, from powershell, write `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-20.04` or whatever your Distro is.
5. Restart your computer!!!
6. When your computer turns back on, you are going to re-install your distro and set it as default. `wsl --install -d <Distribution Name>`
7. Go through the setups, then all I did was `code .` and got the interaction below. It now works for me.

```
drewbie@drewbie:~$ cd ~
drewbie@drewbie:~$ ls
drewbie@drewbie:~$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 drewbie drewbie 4096 Jan 12 18:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root    4096 Jan 12 18:12 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 drewbie drewbie  220 Jan 12 18:12 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 drewbie drewbie 3771 Jan 12 18:12 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 2 drewbie drewbie 4096 Jan 12 18:12 .landscape
-rw-r--r-- 1 drewbie drewbie    0 Jan 12 18:12 .motd_shown
-rw-r--r-- 1 drewbie drewbie  807 Jan 12 18:12 .profile
drewbie@drewbie:~$ code .
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3)
Downloading: 100%
Unpacking: 100%
Unpacked 1722 files and folders to /home/drewbie/.vscode-server/bin/899d46d82c4c95423fb7e10e68eba52050e30ba3.
```

Comment: Excellent - Good to hear you got it working!  A bit drastic anyway, with the WSL/Ubuntu removal and the Windows Terminal settings removal, but glad you are past the problem.  I'm going to make a slight edit to your answer for the sake of "safety", but no biggie.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thank you for your revision! It's true they will lose everything on their instance :(

Comment: That solved my problem! Thanks @drewkiimon

Answer (score 3):

Mine works a bit different compared to @cloudcreatordotio , I add this line to my .bashrc and steps shown below:

1. open your ubuntu shell
2. open the .bashrc

   ```
   nano .bashrc
   ```
3. add the following line

   ```
   alias code="'/mnt/c/Users/[YOUR USER DIR NAME]/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/Code.exe'"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

None of the reasonable solutions for this problem worked for me on a fresh laptop. The root cause turned out to be the order I performed my setup in.

My error:
Prior to launching code I had setup the `/etc/wsl/conf` file to append the Windows Path to the wsl Path as `false`. These `/mnt/c/Windows/`paths can cause issues when doing various development tasks, but apparently they are needed initially for code to work.

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath = false
```

So, when I went to launch `code .` within wsl it didn't know where to find it, as a result.

Fix:

Allow the windows paths to be appeneded

`sudo nano /etc/wsl.conf`

```
[interop]
appendWindowsPath = true
```

Exit out of wsl and then shut it down
`wsl --shutdown`

Get back into wsl and launch code
`code .`

It should install.

Optional:

You can then remove the windows paths from the configuration file once more and add the path in the `~/.bashrc` file:

`export PATH="/mnt/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:$PATH"`